# excluding dependency from common project

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I have three projects right now that form a dependency chain, `Project A` depends on `Project B` depends on `Project C`.

In `Project B`, I am attempting to exclude the `xml-apis` jar that is causing problems with weblogic. I'm doing so like this in `Project B`'s POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

However, the `xml-apis` artifact is still being included when I package Project A. What is the correct way to exclude this `xml-apis` jar? Should I find exactly what package in `Project C` is bringing this in and mark it as provided there?

Right now my workaround is to just list the above dependency in `Project A`'s POM.

EDIT:

`Project A` has a dependency on `Project B` and `Project C`. Since `Project B` has a dependency on `Project C` and `Project B` would never be used without `Project C` I was hoping to not have to include the dependency information in `Project A` and `Project B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project B's pom states that it uses Project C, except that it (Project B) doesn't need the xml-apis.

Project A's pom also states that it uses Project C, but without saying it doesn't need xml-apis, therefore maven assumes it does need them.

You can either add the dependency on xml-apis to Project A with a scope of provided, meaning that yes you need them but you're going to make sure an implementation is available and you don't want maven to include them, or you could remove Project A's dependency on Project C.

Answer (score 0):

Project B does not depend on A. Insert the excludes statement in b's pom on the C dependency.

Comment: I did. The above snippet is from my Project B. See my EDIT.

Comment: just noticed the POM snippet had Project A there. Fixed.

Comment: @Casey you now appear to have a POM saying Project B depends on projectB

Comment: description of the problem is and was accurate though.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, maybe clear but confusing. Just do `mvn dependency:tree`, check and exclude the dependency you need in the correct pom, whether it is A or B or C.